# Display text one character by one

Tags: c#, unity

In a game over screen I am trying to display the text "GAME OVER" one character by one.

```
public float letterPause = 0.2f;
string message;
private TextMesh textComp;

public void DeathMenu()
{   
    GameObject text = GameObject.Find("Text_Score");
    TextMesh textComp = text.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    textComp.text = "GAME OVER";
    message = textComp.text;

    StartCoroutine (AnimateFinalScore ());

}//end of Setup Death Menu

IEnumerator AnimateFinalScore()
{
    foreach (char letter in message.ToCharArray()) {

        textComp.text += letter;

        yield return null;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);
    }
}
```

The code is not working; it generates the following error message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This error message points to the `textComp` variable in the `DeathMenu()` method.

Comment: now the error message points to the textComp.text += letter; variable in the IEnumerator();

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding details in comments. That way it's easier for a new visitor to understand the full issue.

Comment: @Hamza Hasan Thank you its working fine now thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> now the error message points to the textComp.text += letter; variable
>   in the IEnumerator();

The reason for this is the way you've defined the `textComp` variable:

```
public void DeathMenu()
{   
    GameObject text = GameObject.Find("Text_Score");
    TextMesh textComp = text.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    ...
```

By declaring a variable inside the `DeathMenu` method, it is *local to that method's scope*.

This means that any code outside of `DeathMenu`'s curly braces {} can't see the `textComp` variable - in fact it's cleared as soon as `DeathMenu` returns (immediately after starting the coroutine).

This happens even though you've defined `private TextMesh textComp;` as a member variable at the top of the class. By repeating the definition inside `DeathMenu` you are declaring a new local variable with the same name, which masks the member variable. So you never assign any value to the member variable, and it still has the default value of `null` when `AnimateFinalScore` tries to work with it.

So, there are three ways to fix this:

- `Find` and `GetComponent` again inside `AnimateFinalScore()` but this is a bit wasteful.
- make sure the member variable version of `textComp` gets used by removing the `TextMesh` in front of the assignment in `DeathMenu`, so you're no longer declaring a new local variable. The downside to this is that you're holding this reference for the lifetime of the instance, when from what you've shown here you only really need it for the duration of the animation.
- (my recommendation) pass the value of `textComp` when starting the coroutine:

  ```
      ...
      StartCoroutine (AnimateFinalScore (textComp));    
  }//end of Setup Death Menu

  IEnumerator AnimateFinalScore(TextMesh textComp)
  {
      ...
  ```

Now code inside `AnimateFinalScore` knows what `textComp` is, because it's defined within that method's scope as one of its arguments. You can do away with the member variable version entirely, unless you have other code that needs it (in which case, use the second bullet point instead)

Comment: Literally this made me laugh :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to make somethin like this:

```
char[] letters = message.ToCharArray();
```

and then in your foreach:

```
foreach (char letter in letters) {

        textComp.text += letter;

        yield return null;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);
    }
```

Not sure if that's the problem but i once had something similar with a string which I tried to trim. The trim function can't be called on a string like

```
string.Trim();
```

you need to call it like this:

```
string = string.Trim();
```

That might be similar to your problem.